# $.getJSON to get JSONP data

Tags: jquery

I was playing with $.getJSON in the following way to receive an alert but without luck.

Here is the code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "ticker.js?callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            alert(data.price);
        });

    });
</script>
```

And the ticker.js file has only the following line

```
{ticket:'IBM',price:14.57}
```

It is supposed to get an alert "14.57" but I am not getting the alert.

If you would like to see it in action you may try the link,
http://nazmulweb.com/site5/demo/jsonPtest/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a local file, you should remove the `?callback=?` part, like this:

```
var url = "ticker.js";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   alert(data.price);
});
```

If you look at [the `$.getJSON()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), there's this:

> If the URL includes the string `"callback=?"` in the URL, the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the `jsonp` data type in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) for more details.

With JSONP it's expecting `randomFunctioName({ticket:'IBM',price:14.57});` in the response, not *just* the JSON, but a function call...this is how JSONP works cross-domain, by being a `<script>` tag. Since you just want JSON and to process it from a *local* source, remove the `callback=?` piece.

*Edit:* I completely missed the second issue, your current JSON isn't valid and will fail jQuery's checks added in 1.4.  It needs to be this:

```
{ "ticket": "IBM", "price": 14.57 }
```

You can test your JSON for validity here: http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: The file is in the same domain.

Comment: @Hoque - Right...that's my point, and it's *not* JSONP which is what `callback=?` instructs it to be, so just leave it off and you're all set :)

Comment: Even removing "callback=?", I did not get the alert.

Comment: I was trying to test it at first for the same domain and I had a plan to do it in the different domain. However my first attempt did not work.

Comment: @Hoque - There's a second part, that's not valid JSON :)  It needs to be `{ "ticket": "IBM", "price": 14.57 }`, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. After removing the callback and correcting the ticker.js file, it now gives alert in Firefox but no alert in IE8 or IE7. I have made a link here, http://nazmulweb.com/site5/demo/jsonPtest/withoutcallback.aspx

Comment: @Hoque - I'm getting an alert in IE8, make sure to blow away your cache of the old `.js` that may be hanging around.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right. After cleaning the cache, it works perfectly. Now I will try for different domain to have a taste of jSONP.

Comment: While I was trying JSONP with callback? option in different domain I am getting "invalid label" error. What could be the reason?

Comment: @Hoque - It sounds like that domain doesn't support JSONP, it has to support it server-side (it returns `functioName({ JSON })` instead of just `{ JSON }` in the response...it's how it works as a GET request.

Comment: Then what is the way to support JSONP in the domain I am working? Is there anything that I can do with my domain. Thank you.

Comment: @Hoque - Nope, unfortunately nothing you can do, has to be done on the server-side, so their end.